# JavaScript Express returning empty JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Folks,
  I have a function that creates an Object that I would like to return back to the browser.  For some reason, the browser is getting an empty Object without the contents:

```
{
    pName: [ ]
}
```

Here is the object via `console.log(require('util').inspect(projectObject, false, 10));`

```
{ pName:
    [ foo:
        [ nodejs: 
            [ staging: 
                [ 
                    { name: 'i-4a14c51a', id: 'i-4a14c51a' },
                    { name: 'i-19fc094a', id: 'i-19fc094a' },
                ],
              production: 
                [ 
                    { name: 'i-5f14c50f', id: 'i-5f14c50f' },
                    { name: 'i-b1fb0ee2', id: 'i-b1fb0ee2' },
                ]
            ]
       ],
...
```

I would imagine the reason its not returning the object is because it thinks that the first entity is empty.

Where am I making the mistake? The result needs to look liks:

```
"hosts": [
{
  "projectA": [
     {
       "foo": [
          {
            "nodejs": [
          {
        "production": [
                       {
                         "name": "Her blog",
                         "cmd": "ssh username@blog2.example.com"
                       }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
           }
        ]
     },
  ]
```

Comment: JSON's Arrays are just lists. For key/value pairs, use `Object`s -- `{ foo: ... }`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski the result needs to be array of objects...

Comment: The values of `staging` and `production` can still be `Array`s, since they're each a list of `Object`s, but those `Array`s need to be contained within `Object`s to include `foo`, `nodejs`, etc. in the output.

Comment: @Cmag The output from util.inspect is completely malformed JSON. Was this just a copy and paste error? If not I suspect that is at least some of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
{ pName:
    [ foo: // <-- invalid JSON
        [ nodejs: 
            [ staging: 
...
```

If that's the output of an inspector I'd have a look at exactly how the `projectObject` is being constructed (are you creating an array and then assigning something to a property on it? In which case create an object instead).

I'm afraid I'm not sure how I'm expected to get to the requested result with the information available however.